# How to use Azure HDInsight getting charged less

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I am using Azure with Pay-as-you-go subscription. I had experience in creating Spark cluster via HDInsight for myself, and got charged more than expected. After that, I searched how to use it in an economical manner and found people normally delete their clusters to save cost. I wonder if there are any other ways for individual users to use Spark cluster with small expenses. Is there other subscriptions that I can use to save cost? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What size VMs did you choose? Depending on your workload more economical sizes may also work.

Comment: I used D12 (4 cores) and D4 (8 cores). I found D4 is pretty expensive from this page (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/hdinsight/).

Answer (score 1):

Creating and deleting clusters can be automated with PowerShell or ARM templates. You are right that's the typical pattern.

You light also look at [Azure Data Lake Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-lake-analytics/) which is targeted at big data but is a pay-per-query model.

Comment: I see. I should try to automate the process of creating and deleting clusters through PowerShell, and use smaller VM sizes with only a few cores. That will reasonably reduce charge.  I also found the article about how to use Azure Automation for this (http://www.datamic.net/blog/automate-provisioning-hdinsight-clusters-with-powershell-and-azure-automation). Thank.s

Comment: Also take a look at Script Actions as well to automate certain activities on creation time. This will save time on recreating any customization.

Answer (score 0):

Also: Keep an eye on your datasets, especially large ones you don't need. Make sure you've got an efficient columnar format for processing (Parquet, ORC), then compress it with a splittable compression (bzip2, LZO, snappy).

You might even find that sometimes its cheaper to recalculate datasets than to persist it.

It's very easy to accidentally retain a lot more data than you need on WASB, which runs up bills even when your cluster is down.

Finally: do make sure your clusters get torn down. A common practise here, at least for AWS clusters is to use Jenkins to start/stop clusters on a schedule. Looks like Azure automation works well for Azure there.